# How to modify Devise's message on a specific step of its workflow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

After **Sign Up** a new user I get redirected to a **Sign In** page with the following `flash[:alert]` message:

*"You need to sign in or sign up before 
continuing."*

My User model uses Devise's `:confirmable` module so it would be nice if after Sign Up a user would see a modified message instead:

*"Thanks for signing up. We have sent you a confirmational email. Please check your email"*

Is there a way to achieve it?

---

Notes about Devise workflow:

Currently a user has no idea that a confirmational email was sent to him. He will see Devise's failure message only when he tries to Log In using unconfirmed email address:

*"You have to confirm your email address before continuing."*

---

Here's solution:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

I just followed first 2 steps:

1) Create RegistrationsController:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected


  # TODO: will this  method be triggered one day?
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    # '/an/example/path'
    new_user_session_path
  end

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

2) Change routes to:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add devise :confirmable to your models/user.rb

```
devise :confirmable
```

Then, do the migration as:

```
rails g migration add_confirmable_to_devise
```

Will generate db/migrate/YYYYMMDDxxx_add_confirmable_to_devise.rb. Add the following to it in order to do the migration.

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # Note: You can't use change, as User.update_all will fail in the down migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    # add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string # Only if using reconfirmable
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, unique: true
    # User.reset_column_information # Need for some types of updates, but not for update_all.
    # To avoid a short time window between running the migration and updating all existing
    # users as confirmed, do the following
    User.all.update_all confirmed_at: Time.now
    # All existing user accounts should be able to log in after this.
    # Remind: Rails using SQLite as default. And SQLite has no such function :NOW.
    # Use :date('now') instead of :NOW when using SQLite.
    # => execute("UPDATE users SET confirmed_at = date('now')")
    # Or => User.all.update_all confirmed_at: Time.now
  end

  def down
    remove_columns :users, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
    # remove_columns :users, :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
  end
end
```

Do the migration `rake db:migrate`

If not using reconfirmable, update the configuration in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.reconfirmable = false
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @yaru: Please refer this link for more details.....
 https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to `devise.en.yml` file which is in `/config/locales/` directory. Under `devise > registrations`, add `signed_up_but_unconfirmed` and set a value

```
devise:
  registrations:
    signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "Thanks for signing up. We have sent you a confirmational email. Please check your email."
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's strange. I already have  signed_up_but_unconfirmed key: "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please follow the link to activate your account." But it does not get triggered for some reason